# Undefined varibale "game" on stripe charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a stripe card which works perfect however I am using stripe connect for a marketplace where it sends out payment to different users depending on their merchant ID. I am getting an error for "game".

Iv'e also tried defining the varibale game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
 but I get an error 'Couldn't find Game without an ID'

Here's my stripe method:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
    def charge
        price = params[:amount].to_f*100
        Stripe::Charge.create({
            amount: price.to_i,
            currency: 'usd',
            source: params[:stripeToken], # obtained with Stripe.js
            description: 'plan',
            :destination => {
                :amount => price * 94, 
                :account => game.user.merchant_id
              }
          })

        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
          flash[:error] = e.message
          redirect_to new_charge_path
      end
    end
```

`line_items` belongs to `cart` and I have a has_many and belongs to association between `game` and `line_items`.

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    game.price.to_i * quantity.to_i
  end
end
```

Here is my game model:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items
end
```

here is my carts/show.html.erb file

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= link_to 'Keep Shopping', games_path %>

<div>
    <%= render(@cart.line_items) %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= link_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
</div>

<div>
    Total: <%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %> 
</div>



<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div id="content" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <%= hidden_field_tag :cart_id , nil, value: @cart.id %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :amount , nil, id: "amount", value: @line_item.total_price %>
            <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Pay with Card"
                data-key="<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>"
                data-currency="usd"
                class="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':submit').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $button = $(this),
            $form = $button.parents('form');
        var opts = $.extend({}, $button.data(), {
            token: function(result) {
                $form.append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'stripeToken', value: result.id })).submit();
            }
        });
        StripeCheckout.open(opts);
    });
});
</script>
```

So whats going on is games has_many line items. Line items belongs to game and cart. Cart just has many line items

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `game` variable before using it at `LineItemsController#charge`

Smth like `game = Game.find(params[:game_id])` before `Stripe::Charge.create...`

Comment: Ive tried that as well but it says it couldn't find Game without an ID

Comment: @Dbbooke: you don't even need a game, it seems. Just a merchant_id. Maybe `game.user` is the same as `current_user` (but I have no idea). In any case, before using an object, you have to obtain a reference to it _somehow_.

Comment: well current_user would not be the game owner as they would not be purchasing their own game

Comment: I'd say you need to hidden game_id input to the form. Can you share snippet with the form? @Dbbooke